# How to know if object is view or table in Imapla/Hive

Tags: view, hive, impala

Do we have system tables/commands to know if an object is a table or view in Impala? 
I may use show tables but it returns views as well.
This question is about hive 1.1

Answer (score 2):

Use describe command:

```
DESCRIBE [FORMATTED] [db_name.]table_name[.complex_col_name ...]
```

For views it will display the text of the query from the view definition.

See here: [DESCRIBE](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_describe.html)

Answer (score 0):

To list the `VIEWS` in Hive

```
SHOW VIEWS [IN/FROM database_name] [LIKE 'pattern_with_wildcards'];
```

Usage examples from [Hive manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ShowViews)

```
SHOW VIEWS;                                -- show all views in the current database
SHOW VIEWS 'test_*';                       -- show all views that start with "test_"
SHOW VIEWS '*view2';                       -- show all views that end in "view2"
SHOW VIEWS LIKE 'test_view1|test_view2';   -- show views named either "test_view1" or "test_view2"
SHOW VIEWS FROM test1;                     -- show views from database test1
SHOW VIEWS IN test1;                       -- show views from database test1 (FROM and IN are same)
SHOW VIEWS IN test1 "test_*";              -- show views from database test2 that start with "test_"
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, but my hive version is 1.1 so this does not work there.

Comment: I see, so do you have embedded metastore or local metastore?